# How to show missing rows with default values

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table `Category` which has a few missing records for a few months. The table looks like this

```
Category    Month       Amount
Opt         January     12.00
Opt         February    0.00
Opt         March       -1042000.00
Opt         April       0.00
Opt         May         0.00
Opt         June        0.00
Opt         July        -782663.00
Opt         November    0.00
Opt         December    0.00
```

This table has missing rows for a few months. I would like to query and show this data as well.

So I created a month table

```
MonthNameLong   MonthNameShort
January         Jan
February        Feb
March           Mar
April           Apr
May             May
June            Jun
July            Jul
August          Aug
September       Sep
October         Oct
November        Nov
December        Dec
```

So that I can do a right join on this and get the missing details as well. The query I wrote is

```
select s.Category, m.MonthNameLong, coalesce(s.Amount, 0.0) as Amount
from Category s
RIGHT JOIN Month m 
ON s.Month = m.MonthNameLong
```

And the result I get is

```
Category    MonthNameLong   Amount
Opt         January         12.00
Opt         February        0.00
Opt         March           -1042000.00
Opt         April           0.00
Opt         May             0.00
Opt         June            0.00
Opt         July            -782663.00
NULL        August          0.00
NULL        September       0.00
NULL        October         0.00
Opt         November        0.00
Opt         December        0.00
```

But instead of NULL category is there a way I can get Opt as the category.

I have attached the fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7sycoGZ4sYxNzdYeTvJauC/0

This is very similar to [SQL join query to show rows with non-existent rows in one table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53151/sql-join-query-to-show-rows-with-non-existent-rows-in-one-table) question but that has all the data in the table so there isn't missing rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle with:

- add one more category for to see the query is correct when there is more than 1 category
- alter amounts making category amount sets different and altering zero values for to see the records inserted additionally.

Edited [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7sycoGZ4sYxNzdYeTvJauC/1).

The final query is

```
With 
Categories AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Category
  FROM Category
  ),
MonthCategories AS (
  SELECT m.MonthNameLong, cat.Category
  FROM Month m, Categories cat
  )

select mc.Category, mc.MonthNameLong, coalesce(cat.Amount, 0.0) as Amount
FROM MonthCategories mc
LEFT JOIN Category cat ON cat.Month = mc.MonthNameLong
                      AND cat.Category = mc.Category;
```

Of course you may "pack" the query combining CTEs to one and/or moving CTEs to subquery.

**PS.** If there is only one category in the table you may simply replace `s.Category` with `MAX(s.Category) OVER (ORDER BY s.Category) as Category` in output list of your initial query.