# Why does Recursive CTE estimate just 1 row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cte, recursive, cardinality-estimates

Given two cascading, self-contained (no real tables) recursive CTE's:

```
create view NumberSequence_0_100_View
as
with NumberSequence as
(
    select 0 as Number
    union all
    select Number + 1
      from NumberSequence    
     where Number < 100
)
select Number
  from NumberSequence;
go

create view NumberSequence_0_10000_View
as
select top 10001
       v100.Number * 100 + v1.Number as Number
  from Common.NumberSequence_0_100_View v100
 cross join Common.NumberSequence_0_100_View v1
 where v1.Number < 100
   and v100.Number * 100 + v1.Number <= 10000
    -- please resist complaining about "order by in view" for this question
 order by v100.Number * 100 + v1.Number 
go
```

Then generate estimate/actual plans for:

```
select * from NumberSequence_0_10000_View
```

Estimate
[image]
Actual
[image: CascadingCtePlan]

Runtime 23ms but estimating just one row for final output (2 rows for just the first view).

The problem is that when this is used as a subquery to join with real data (by "DaysAgo" for instance), the plan is usually a very slow nested loop and I often need to add a join hint/reverse order etc.

Is there anyway to improve the estimate while keeping the CTE approach?  Has there ever been a request for a "with (AssumeMinRows=N)" hint?  That seems like a great general purpose helper for many cases (not just CTEs).

Comment: Instead of trying to coerce a CTE to work the way you want, why not just put a Numbers table on disk (and hence in memory), and stop generating sets of numbers with recursion?

Comment: The example is just there to demonstrate the problem.  I assume this happens for more general CTE's sometimes (I can't come up with a case right now though).   Does no one care that the estimate for a cross of 100 x 100 is 1? The question says "...while keeping the CTE approach."  Just answering "Why" for this specific case would be acceptable and help unravel some mystery.

Comment: @crokusek you know it's 100x100 but the optimizer does not enough math to figure out that the first view will always yield 100 rows (sorry 101 and then you'll strip them to 100). That's another reason to have a permanent table, the optimizer will have indexes and statistics available.

Comment: @ypercube well, it "does not enough math" is a kind of an answer. For instance why not see the top "N" and use "N" as the estimate?  A 1 row estimate does not seem probable for any CTE. Since plans may don't change until some cost threshold is crossed maybe they chose 1 since it has same effect as 50 which might be just as bad a guess for a fixed CTE, etc.  Along those lines...  Is someone certain that anything not based on row statistics will always estimate 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Why does Recursive CTE estimate just 1 row?*

Cardinality estimation for recursive common table expressions is extremely limited.

Under the original cardinality estimation model, the estimate is a simple sum of the cardinality estimates for the anchor and recursive parts. This is equivalent to assuming the recursive part is executed exactly once.

In SQL Server 2014, with the new cardinality estimation model enabled, the logic is slightly changed to assume three executions of the recursive part, with the same number of rows returned by each iteration.

Both of these are uneducated guesses, so it is no surprise that the use of recursive CTes usually results in poor quality estimations. More generally, estimating the result of a recursive process is nigh-on impossible, so the optimizer doesn't even try. This is not changed by using a particularly simple recursive structure, clearly intended to produce sequential numbers - the optimizer has no logic to detect this pattern.

In your particular case, the final estimation is one because the optimizer makes further guesses about the selectivity of predicates like `[Recr1007]<(100)` (in the Filter at Node ID 3) and `([Recr1003]*(100)+[Recr1007])<=(10000)` (the residual predicate on the Nested Loops Join at Node ID 2). Again, these are guesses, and the results are unfortunate, though not surprising.

> *Is there anyway to improve the estimate while keeping the CTE approach?*

Not that I am aware of.

> *Has there ever been a request for a "with (AssumeMinRows=N)" hint?*

Not directly in those terms. There have been plenty of requests for [materializing a CTE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables), which would help if such materialization came with automatic statistics generation. I won't list the others because you seem to have commented on most of those suggestions already :)

There have also been suggestions for [selectivity hints](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/649342/allow-to-specify-filter-selectivity-hint-in-queries), but nothing like this has made its way into the product yet.

As noted in comments on the question, your best bet right now is to use a real [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) instead of generating one on-the-fly using a recursive CTE. A second option is to use manual materialization - a temporary table - as I am sure you are aware.