# How can I improve performance on a 3 table query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I'm attempting to analyze a resource drawdown (the percentage of time individual units are being utilized during a reporting period, e.g. 2-weeks or 1-year).  I need the aggregation down to the minute.  To accomplish this, I'm querying two tables and a view, but it's taking approximately 1 hour per execution so I'm trying to improve its performance.

**My Setup**

**View 1** holds my time intelligence for period reporting.  It's based upon a customized calendar table that uses date as its primary level of aggregation.  This is my primary filter for values, returning 14 rows for a bi-weekly reporting period.

**Table 1** is a calendar table, with values to the minute.  It has values for a period of 20 years, so there are in excess of 10.5 million records.  This table provides the level of detail I need for my analysis.

**Table 2** is a proprietary table from our RMS vendor and holds the resource utilization records necessary for the analysis.  It resides in a separate database (on the same server) as Table 1 and View 1, and I can't make any changes to it.  For a biweekly period, it will return approximately 350 rows.

**My Problem**
For a period of time defined through View 1, I need to return all of the rows from Table 1 left joined to Table 2.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT t1.calendar_dttm, t2.unit, t2.start_dttm, t2.end_dttm
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 on  t1.calendar_dttm >= t2.start_dttm 
                     and t1.calendar_dttm <=t2.end_dttm
JOIN View_1 v1 on  t1.calendar_dttm >= v1.start_dttm 
               and t1.calendar_dttm <= v1.end_dttm
WHERE v1.period_diff = -1
```

This takes 24.5 mins to return 26855 rows, and eventually I'll need to run it for year (or more) long periods of time.

**EDIT:**  As I look at the execution plan, I think I need to filter both tables for the reporting period before conducting the joins.  Here's the execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

And here's View_1:

```
SELECT 
c1.[Date ID]
, c1.Date
, c1.DAY
, c1.DayofMonth
, c1.DayofWeek
, c1.Week
, c1.MONTH
, c1.YEAR
, c1.Shift
, c1.DayofPayperiod
, c1.DayofFLSA
, c1.PayPeriod
, c1.paydate
, c1.flsa_end
, FLOOR(((CONVERT(float,(c1.[Date]-GETDATE()))+(14-c1.[DayofPayPeriod]))/14)) period_diff
, DATEDIFF(yy,GETDATE(), c1.date) year_cal_diff
, DATEPART(dy,c1.date) doy
, DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date) day_offset
, CASE
    when DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date) < 0 
    then '-'
    else '+'
    end + right('0000'+ REPLACE(DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date),'-',''),4)
    day_offset_label
, CEILING(FLOOR(((CONVERT(float,(c1.[Date]-GETDATE()))+(14-c1.[DayofPayPeriod]))/14))/26) year_run_diff
, DATEADD(HH,7,c1.Date) shift_start,DATEADD(s,111599,c1.date) shift_end


FROM Table_Calendar c1
```

It takes static, custom date data from a table and then applies calculates dynamic period info based upon the date its run.

Comment: There are only 20160 minutes in 14 days, but you get 26855. Are you sure you apply the correct logic? Can you add the DDL and some example rows?

Comment: @dnoeth, good catch on the row numbers.  Each "extra" row above the 20,160 indicates that additional resources were used during that minute.  An equally acceptable solution would have had 16,896 rows-the number where there was a value in unit/start_dttm/end_dttm fields and ignoring the 9959 rows where there was a null value (indicative that there were no resources in use during those times).

Answer (score 1):

I see joins to v1 on start_dttm and end_dttm but dont see it in the view or the table listed.

Looking at your definition of your view, are you sure this is an issue with the join, or does the view itself have issues?

There are a few problems, and I will list them in order my brain saw them:

`, DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date) day_offset
, CASE
    when DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date) < 0 
    then '-'
    else '+'
    end + right('0000'+ REPLACE(DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE()+(14-(select DayofPayPeriod from Table_Calendar where date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))),date),'-',''),4)
    day_offset_label`

These sections of the query indicate you might have RBAR behavior, eg the queries in the parenthesis may be running for each row that you need to return, as you add more data this will take longer and longer.

Of the columns you use that I can see:

`FLOOR(((CONVERT(float,(c1.[Date]-GETDATE()))+(14-c1.[DayofPayPeriod]))/14))`

Uses a calculation which is not SARGable in anyway, and so that -1 comparison would need to be calculated for each row as well.

This may be a case where the execution plan's estimates vs actual rows would be off, you may want to download a tool such as SQL Sentry Plan Explorer (dont need to buy the pro version to easily compare things like this http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) which will highlight problem areas.

From what I can see of the plan (not much) it is giving me the impression that the planner cannot produce a useful plan and causing you to have a bad time.

My recommendations:

- Compare like types so that you can use an index, or worst case make some sort of materialized view if you cant. See if you can unwrap some of those calculations and use less human readable/nice numbers to evaluate date offsets.

  - You may need to add an index or two to make this fly.
- Consider using a numbers table to calculate offsets or values needed for far in the future, [Why are numbers tables "invaluable"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) so that you can use the power of the index to query this instead of churn your CPU each time you run this query.
- Try to query some of this information in a SARGable fashion and then do the gross formatting work on a temp table or something that is your "final set", if this is still to slow you may want to consider doing this in some other programming paradigm.

Comment: +1, Thank you for the direction.  You've thrown out some new terms for me to research (e.g. RBAR, SARG).  I'm really interested in the Numbers Table concept-I've never liked how the view works-so I'll definitely be pursuing that (plus any question by Jeff Atwood is probably going to lead to good learning).

Comment: Row by agonizing row and search argument able, inducing behavior that is not set based and queries which are able to use an index to narrow their results(theres more but thats the jist) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reduce the query time from 24.5 minutes to 2.5 minutes by making a minor change in the query joins.  The modified query makes the initial select statement from my view (14 rows for a biweekly period), and that filters both of the tables down to only the relevant rows.

The new query is:

```
SELECT t1.calendar_dttm, t2.unit, t2.start_dttm, t2.end_dttm
FROM View_1 v1
JOIN Table_1 t1 on t1.calendar_dttm >= v1.start_dttm AND t1.Calendar_dttm <= v1.end_dttm
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 on t1.calendar_dttm >= t2.start_dttm AND t1.calendar_dttm <= t2.end_dttm
WHERE v1.period_diff = -1
```

And it's Execution Plan:

[image]