# Validating an HTML input string

Tags: sql-server

A partial solution is to get all the `Notes (VARCHAR)` where there is an imbalance in `<` and `>`. But how can I write a query for that?

For example:

```
Input: <html>Hello World</html>
Output: Valid HTML

Input: <html><Hello World</html>
Output: Invalid HTML

Input: <html><Hello World></html>
Output: Valid HTML (Marking it Valid is OK for my use case)
But hey isn't that a valid HTML? It could be <name attribute>
```

Are there any better ways to check for "invalid" HTML where "invalid" is defined as HTML content with `<` followed some characters that is not a valid `HTML Element` as per specification?

Initially I thought I could check for `<name` followed by a  (Space) but HTML Attributes have syntax as `<name attribute` and closed by `>` at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want to do is confirm that the input string consists of a sequence of `<...>` elements:

1. Split the string on the `<` character using your favourite string splitter
2. The first element must be blank
3. Subsequent elements must contain exactly one `>` character

The input string is valid if every element passes the tests above.

### Example

#### String splitter

I am using the `SQL#.String_Split4k` streaming table-valued function from the free edition of the SQLCLR [SQLsharp library](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) by Solomon Rutzky.

If the input string might be longer than 4000 characters, the (less efficient) `SQL#.String_Split` function would be used instead (it handles strings up to 2GB).

Any *efficient* [string splitter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11564/1192) (T-SQL or otherwise) that can return empty elements correctly with a sequence number will work.

The example below shows the sort of output `SQL#.String_Split4k` returns.

The first parameter is the string to split. The second parameter is the delimiter. The third parameter (*SplitOption*) is set to 1, which means Keep Empty Elements.

```
SELECT
    SS.SplitNum,
    SS.SplitVal
FROM SQL#.String_Split4k(N'<a><b><c>', N'<', 1) AS SS;
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ SplitNum ║ SplitVal ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║        1 ║          ║
║        2 ║ a>       ║
║        3 ║ b>       ║
║        4 ║ c>       ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

#### Table and test data

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
    row_id integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    string varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT #T 
    (string)
VALUES 
    ('<html>Hello World</html>'),
    ('<html><Hello World</html>'),
    ('<html><Hello World></html>');
```

#### Solution

```
SELECT
    T.row_id,
    string = (SELECT TOP (1) T2.string FROM #T AS T2 WHERE T2.row_id = T.row_id),
    is_valid =
        MIN
        (
            CASE
                -- First element must be blank
                WHEN SS.SplitNum = 1 AND SS.SplitVal = N'' THEN 1
                WHEN SS.SplitNum = 1 THEN 0
                -- Other elements must contain exactly one >
                WHEN SS.SplitVal NOT LIKE N'%>%' THEN 0
                WHEN SS.SplitVal LIKE N'%>%>%' THEN 0
                -- Otherwise valid
                ELSE 1
            END
        )
FROM #T AS T
CROSS APPLY SQL#.String_Split4k(T.string, '<', 1) AS SS
GROUP BY T.row_id
ORDER BY T.row_id;
```

#### Output

```
╔════════╦════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ row_id ║           string           ║ is_valid ║
╠════════╬════════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ <html>Hello World</html>   ║        1 ║
║      2 ║ <html><Hello World</html>  ║        0 ║
║      3 ║ <html><Hello World></html> ║        1 ║
╚════════╩════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```