# Return number of rows based on column value

Tags: stored-procedures, functions

We are administering a sweepstakes for a client where we have a GUID tied to a contestant and the number of entries the contestant has acquired. I want to be able to draw winners based on the chance of winning corresponding to the number of entries.

```
GUID | Entries
--------------
1    | 1
2    | 5
3    | 2
4    | 7
```

So the results would be:

```
GUID
----
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

Basically I plan put the results in a spreadsheet and then use a random number generator to pick a row number between 1 and n, where n is the total number of entries. But of course if there is a way to easily select the winner programmatically, I'm all ears (or eyes as the case may be).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Is there an `Entries` table?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want that to be done on the database? You normally want to offload on the DB anything that saves unnecessary data being sent to the client, but in this particular case you are doing the opposite (you want the database to send you redundant data).

_I plan put the results in a spreadsheet and then use a random number generator to pick a row number between 1 and n_ 

Why not return the first raw results and use a weight function on your random number (1:1 wins; 2:2-6: wins, etc.)?

Comment: Other answers provide a way to get the data you want.  As an alternative to exporting to spreadsheet I reccomend you look into Order By NewID()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For interest's sake, here is a solution for SQL Server 2016 that uses the built-in [pseudo]random number generator to pick a winner for you.

First, the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(ID int,
Entries int)

INSERT #t
VALUES
(1,1),
(2,5),
(3,2),
(4,7)
```

Then the code:

```
DECLARE @r float = RAND()

SELECT TOP 1 ID, @r
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
    Entries,
    SUM(Entries) OVER(ORDER BY ID) / CONVERT(float,SUM(Entries) OVER()) AS RunningFraction
    FROM #t
) RF
WHERE RunningFraction > @r
ORDER BY ID
```

You can skip the variable declaration and just use `WHERE RunningFraction > RAND()`, but this format makes it easier to test the functionality.

Comment: I tried this option first because it specified SQL Server 2016. Sorry for not tagging the question properly.

Answer (score 9):

For Postgres you can use:

```
select guid, g.i
from the_table
  cross join lateral generate_series(1, entries) as g(i);
```

Comment: Short and to the point. (On 9.6, it even works without `lateral`, and without g.i).

Answer (score 4):

Using Sql Server (2016 in my case), this gave me the answer you wanted - (not fully tested and probably many other methods).

This technique uses a Sql Server [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
set nocount on
Declare @GuidEntries table (Guid int, Entries int)
insert into @GuidEntries values(1, 1)
insert into @GuidEntries values(2, 5)
insert into @GuidEntries values(3, 2)
insert into @GuidEntries values(4, 7)

;WITH cteGuidEntries  AS
(
    SELECT guid, entries from @GuidEntries
    UNION ALL
    SELECT guid, entries - 1
    FROM cteGuidEntries
    WHERE entries > 1
)
SELECT guid from cteGuidEntries 
order by guid
```

Comment: Nice recursive CTE.  You may want to either describe how that part works, or provide a link to Microsoft's CTE docs.  Also, you may want to clean up unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any DBMS this won't work on, but there is a little more prep work for you. Specifically, you need to build a numbers table with values from 1 to at least `max possible number of entries`. Build this however you want - there are dozens of pieces of code out there giving examples of how to build this type of table. Make the number the table's PK.  For this example, I'll call the table `Numbers`, and the number field `num` (creativity!)

```
INSERT INTO EndTable (guid)
SELECT guid
FROM GUID_Entries e
INNER JOIN Numbers n
   ON n.num <= e.entries
```

Comment: Maybe you should add details on how to create the numbers table, or perhaps link to the [canonical numbers table question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable).

Comment: I hadn't seen the canonical numbers table question before - I started using them before that post was ever made - so thanks for linking that in. Mainly, I didn't give an example because there was no specific DBMS specified. While that example works fine in SQL Server, it fails in PostgreSQL, Oracle, Firebird, MySql, etc... Posting an answer that doesn't work for the questioner can leave them more confused that just saying "work it out yourself."

Comment: Point taken!  I'd venture to *guess* this is a question about [tag:sql-server] since the OP has tagged it [tag:sql] which is far too often confused with actual tag for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Laughing Vergil's answer(+1), but Oracle specific and generates the rows needed on demand based on the largest number of entries.

```
SELECT ge.guid
FROM GuidEntries ge
JOIN (
   SELECT level lv FROM DUAL 
   CONNECT BY Level <= (SELECT MAX(ge2.entries) FROM GuidEntries ge2)
   ) l ON l.lv <= ge.entries
ORDER BY GUID;
```

Setup:

```
--DROP TABLE GuidEntries;
CREATE TABLE GuidEntries (Guid Number(1), Entries Number(1));
INSERT ALL 
   INTO GuidEntries VALUES (1,1)
   INTO GuidEntries VALUES (2,5)
   INTO GuidEntries VALUES (3,2)
   INTO GuidEntries VALUES (4,7)
   SELECT * FROM dual;
```

To also get back a random row, do the following:

```
SELECT guid FROM
(
SELECT ge.guid
FROM GuidEntries ge
JOIN (
   SELECT level lv FROM DUAL 
   CONNECT BY Level <= (SELECT MAX(ge2.entries) FROM GuidEntries ge2)
   ) l ON l.lv <= ge.entries
ORDER BY DBMS_Random.Random
) WHERE rownum<=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very clumsy, but the technique might come in handy for other purposes. Using a cube as a generator and a window function to filter rows:

```
with t(guid,entries) as ( 
    values (1,1),(2,5),(3,2),(4,7)
) 
select guid from (
    select guid, entries, row_number() over (
                                  partition by guid
                                  order by guid asc nulls last
                                         , entries asc nulls last) as rn
    from t 
    group by cube(guid, guid, entries, entries)
) as x
where guid is not null 
  and rn <= entries

GUID       
-----------
      1
      2
      2
      2
      2
      2
      3
      3
      4
      4
      4
      4
      4
      4
      4
```

I would not bet my life on it, but ordering by rand() and fetching the first row might reflect the probability determined by entries

```
....
where guid is not null 
  and rn <= entries+1
order by rand()
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Note that we need an `ORDER BY` in the `WINDOW` clause, otherwise a null might occupy a low row_number. It appears as if both Postgresql and DB2 by default orders nulls last, this might not be the case for other vendors so for safety reasons it's probably best to explicitly declare this.

Comment: I think you're of by 1 (if I reproduce this on PostgreSQL, I get 2 ones, 6 twos, 3 threes,

Comment: @joanolo, thanks for poibnting this out. The query where non-deterministic which caused different behavior. I updated the query and tested with `PostgreSQL 9.5.5` and `DB2 10.5.6`

Answer (score -1):

Not exact as it will miss missing entries but it probably does what you want

```
set nocount on
Declare @GuidEntries table (Guid int, Entries int)
insert into @GuidEntries values(1, 1)
insert into @GuidEntries values(2, 5)
insert into @GuidEntries values(3, 2)
insert into @GuidEntries values(4, 7)
insert into @GuidEntries values(5, 1)
insert into @GuidEntries values(6, 2)

select g.Guid 
from @GuidEntries g
join (select distinct entries from @GuidEntries) ge
      on g.Entries >= ge.Entries 
order by g.Guid
```

Could even get a random

```
with cte as 
(
select g.Guid, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by g.GUID) as rn
from @GuidEntries g
join (select distinct entries from @GuidEntries) ge
      on g.Entries >= ge.Entries 
)
--select select C1.Guid FROM CTE C1
select C1.Guid, C1.rn 
FROM CTE C1 
where C1.rn = (select cast(rand()*count(*) as int) + 1  from cte)
```

If you have small max on entries
But I like the answer from Scott better

```
select GUID from talble where Entries = 1 
union all 
select GUID from talble where Entries = 2 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 3 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 4 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 5 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 6 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 7 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 8 
union all
select GUID from talble where Entries = 9
```

Comment: Oops - You mean for all of those WHERE clauses _where Entries **>=**_, right?

Comment: Really dv a working answer?

Comment: @LaughingVergil No - it works for me