# Query to categorize rows based on a "time" column without using a CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, optimization, query-performance

There is a `ProductTT` table as you can see below:

```
[dbo].[ProductTT] (ID int , Product Varchar(50) , Time Int)
```

...which contains the following rows:

```
1   XX   0030
2   UY   0354
3   YY   0517
4   ZZ   0712
5   WW   0415
6   GG   1112
7   MM   1030
8   HH   0913
```

*Note*: The format of the data in `time` column is `hh:mm` so *0030* is *00:30*.

I want to write a query to categorize the rows based on their `time` value. I need to have 4 categories like this:

```
category1   00 to 03
category2   03 to 06
category3   06 to 09
category4   09 to 12
```

I need to see how many rows pertain to each category.

#### My attempt so far

What I've written so far is like this:

```
With CTE
AS (select ID,
       product,
       [time],
       Case
         When left(time,2)>=00 and left(time,2)< 03  then  'group1'
         when left(time,2)>=03 and left(time,2)< 06  then  'group2'
         when left(time,2)>=06 and left(time,2)< 09  then  'group3'
         when left(time,2)>=09 and left(time,2)<=12  then  'group4' End AS groupID
from [dbo].[ProductTT]

)
 select groupid,count(*) as recordcount
 from cte
 group by groupid
```

#### My question

That query works fine but I just want to know whether there are better ways to write this query and avoid using a CASE expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stored `Time` as an `int` but then displayed it as a string (with leading zeros). Those don't get stored, so in order to perform calculations that need to handle the leading zeros, you need to convert to a string first (your current query doesn't do this, so either your query doesn't work, or that table structure is not accurate). Since this is a linear calculation (groups of 3), you can simplify away the `CASE` expression by simply dividing the first two digits in the time by 3 (and thanks to SQL Server's integer division, the remainder gets discarded, and we add 1 to go from 0-3 to 1-4). Of course, there is an exception, because you want 12 PM to be in group 4, not group 5. With a `CASE` expression this could just be left to the `ELSE` clause, but if you eliminate `CASE`, you will have to deal with that exception explicitly - that's all the `COALESCE`/`NULLIF` stuff at the end.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Product, [Time] = RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(varchar(4),[Time]),4) 
  FROM dbo.ProductTT
), y AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Product, [Time], h = CONVERT(char(2),[Time]) 
  FROM x
)
SELECT ID, Product, [Time], 
  [GroupID] = 'group' + CONVERT(char(1),h/3+1-COALESCE(NULLIF(h%11,1)-h%11,1))
FROM y;
```

Results:

```
ID  Product  Time   GroupID
--  -------  ----   -------
1   XX       0030   group1
2   UY       0354   group2
3   YY       0517   group2
4   ZZ       0712   group3
5   WW       0415   group2
6   GG       1112   group4
7   MM       1030   group4
8   HH       0913   group4
```

I strongly recommend you use the actual `time` data type, as that is what it was designed for. Then you can use `DATEPART(HOUR(` in your calculations instead of messy string manipulation, the query above is less complex and, as a bonus, you get built-in validation, to avoid invalid times like `1369` and `9997`. Or if the leading zeros are important but you don't care about validation, use `char(4)` instead of `int`.

I also think you need to handle the case where an event happens in the afternoon.

And FWIW I am not sure why you don't want to use a `CASE` expression here. It's a few more characters, sure, but it's a *lot* more clear what the query is actually doing. Code that is self-documenting is much more valuable than code that is slightly shorter. This is simpler IMHO, and would be even simpler if you used the right data types:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Product, [Time] = RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(varchar(4),[Time]),4) 
  FROM dbo.ProductTT
)
SELECT ID, Product, [Time],
  GroupID = 'group' + CASE CONVERT(char(2),[Time])/3
    WHEN 0 THEN '1'
    WHEN 1 THEN '2'
    WHEN 2 THEN '3'
    ELSE '4' END 
FROM x;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) to categorize the values in dbo.ProductTT.

I've created a simple [MCVE](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/mcve?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.stackexchange.com&utm_campaign=237015)<sup>1</sup> to show how this works.  FYI, in future, it would be great if you'd provide code like this when asking a question.  It helps everyone.

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ProductTT', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.ProductTT;
END
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductTT
(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , Product varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , CreateTime int NOT NULL
    , FormattedCreateTime AS RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4), CreateTime), 4)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductTT
VALUES (1, 'XX', 0030)
    , (2, 'UY', 0354)
    , (3, 'YY', 0517)
    , (4, 'ZZ', 0712)
    , (5, 'WW', 0415)
    , (6, 'GG', 1112)
    , (7, 'MM', 1030)
    , (8, 'HH', 0913)
    , (9, 'H1', 1230)
    , (10, 'H2', 1359)
    , (11, 'H3', 2359);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TimeGroups', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.TimeGroups;
END
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeGroups
(
    TimeGroupStart int NOT NULL
    , TimeGroupEnd int NOT NULL
    , TimeGroupName varchar(9) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TimeGroupStart, TimeGroupEnd)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TimeGroups (TimeGroupStart, TimeGroupEnd, TimeGroupName)
VALUES (0,  3,  '00 to 03')
     , (3,  6,  '03 to 06')
     , (6,  9,  '06 to 09')
     , (9,  12, '09 to 12')
     , (12, 15, '12 to 15')
     , (15, 18, '15 to 18')
     , (18, 21, '18 to 21')
     , (21, 24, '21 to 24');
```

The "numbers table" in the code above is called "TimeGroups".

To get the desired output, you simply join the two tables together, as in:

```
SELECT tg.TimeGroupName
    , TimeGroupCount = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.ProductTT tt
    INNER JOIN dbo.TimeGroups tg ON (tt.CreateTime / 100) >= tg.TimeGroupStart
        AND (tt.CreateTime / 100) < tg.TimeGroupEnd
GROUP BY tg.TimeGroupName
ORDER BY tg.TimeGroupName;
```

The output looks like:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ TimeGroupName ║ TimeGroupCount ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 00 to 03      ║              1 ║
║ 03 to 06      ║              3 ║
║ 06 to 09      ║              1 ║
║ 09 to 12      ║              3 ║
║ 12 to 15      ║              2 ║
║ 21 to 24      ║              1 ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Note that the `JOIN` clause in the above query specifies the range as greater-than-or-equal to the start of the category, and *less-than* the end of the category.  If you used *less-than-or-equal-to* for the end of the range, you'd have `ProductTT` rows showing up in multiple categories, which is clearly incorrect.

You can see how the join works with this simple query:

```
SELECT tt.*
    , Category = tt.CreateTime / 100
FROM dbo.ProductTT tt
```

The output looks like:

```
╔════╦═════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ Product ║ CreateTime ║ FormattedCreateTime ║ Category ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ XX      ║         30 ║                0030 ║        0 ║
║  2 ║ UY      ║        354 ║                0354 ║        3 ║
║  3 ║ YY      ║        517 ║                0517 ║        5 ║
║  4 ║ ZZ      ║        712 ║                0712 ║        7 ║
║  5 ║ WW      ║        415 ║                0415 ║        4 ║
║  6 ║ GG      ║       1112 ║                1112 ║       11 ║
║  7 ║ MM      ║       1030 ║                1030 ║       10 ║
║  8 ║ HH      ║        913 ║                0913 ║        9 ║
║  9 ║ H1      ║       1230 ║                1230 ║       12 ║
║ 10 ║ H2      ║       1359 ║                1359 ║       13 ║
║ 11 ║ H3      ║       2359 ║                2359 ║       23 ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

---

<sup>1 - I own the website pointed to in that link</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the hour part of the time string and divide it by three. The integer of this division plus 1 is equal to your group number.

(00/3) + 1 = 1

(01/3) + 1 = 1

(02/3) + 1 = 1

(03/3) + 1 = 2

(04/3) + 1 = 2

...

In that way you will no longer need the case.

To explain a little further; you use the case because you want to know if the time belongs to the group1, group2 and so on. One way to avoid the case is to figure out what group the time belongs using the formulas that I give to you. You can calculate the groupId field using that formula: "group"&((to_int(to_int(left(time,2)))/3)+1). I do not know the function to convert string to int in your database so a used to_int in the example.