# CONVERT COLUMN INTO ROW

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this .

```
    ID   COUNT
    A1   2
    B2   2
    C1   1
```

i want output like this

```
ID
A1
A1
B2
B2
C1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is:

1. Determine the highest value for `[COUNT]` (if you know this can't be more than 10 or 20 or `<some number>`, just hard-code it as `<that> + 1` or `<that> * 2`).
2. Generate a sequence of numbers, and join to it (producing for any given ID a row for each integer up to and including `[COUNT]`).

   ```
   DECLARE @n int = (SELECT MAX([COUNT]) FROM dbo.table);

   ;WITH n(n) AS 
   (
     SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < @n
   )
   SELECT t.ID FROM dbo.table AS t
     INNER JOIN n ON n.n <= t.[COUNT]
     ORDER BY t.ID;
   ```

   If `[COUNT]` can be > 100, you'll need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)`, because recursive CTEs are by default limited to 100.
3. If you have a numbers table (and [everyone should, IMHO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/1186)) that starts at 1 and includes the highest possible value for `[COUNT]`, it's slightly simpler, since you don't need to pre-determine the end of the range:

   ```
   SELECT t.ID FROM dbo.table AS t
     INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n 
       ON n.NumberColumn <= t.[COUNT]
     ORDER BY t.ID;
   ```

   If your numbers table starts at 0, you'll need an additional clause to prevent 0 from adding an extra row for every ID:

   ```
       ON n.NumberColumn > 0 AND n.NumberColumn <= t.[COUNT]
   ```

Comment: YES. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT MAX([count]) maxcount
          FROM datatable
        ), 
cte2 AS ( SELECT 1 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num+1 FROM cte1, cte2 WHERE num < maxcount
            )
SELECT id
FROM datatable, cte2
WHERE [count] >= num
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I will say that the old [`table1, table2` join syntax is terrible](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and shouldn't be used anywhere, never mind taught to newer users.