# Add missing month in a table of values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following entries:

| customer_ID | lastDate | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2012-04-30' | 5 |
| 1 | '2012-06-30' | 4 |
| 1 | '2013-07-31' | 25 |
| 2 | '2012-04-30' | 7 |
| 2 | '2012-05-31' | 4 |
| 2 | '2012-06-30' | 1 |
| 2 | '2012-07-31' | 6 |

I need to add missing month and the date which gets added should be the last date of that month with frequency value as 0.

The expected output is:

| customer_ID | lastDate | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-30 | 5 |
| 1 | 2012-05-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-06-30 | 4 |
| 1 | 2012-07-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-08-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-09-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-10-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-11-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-12-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-01-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-02-28 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-03-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-04-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-05-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-06-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 25 |
| 2 | 2012-04-30 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-05-31 | 4 |
| 2 | 2012-06-30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012-07-31 | 6 |

I need to add missing month and the date which gets added should be the last date of that.

We can achieve this using CTE method. But can a similar result be obtained using joins?

Solution through CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, date, frequency,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
      union all
      select id, eomonth(date, 1), 0, next_date
      from cte
      where eomonth(date, 1) < dateadd(day, -1, next_date)
     )
select id, date, frequency
from cte
order by id, date;
```

I am trying to build a data pipeline and when I run this on that editor, it does not support recursive CTEs. I have no options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a [table of numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable), or can access the built-in table in `master`:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    Expanded.[date],
    Expanded.frequency
FROM 
(
    -- Add next date for the current id
    SELECT
        T.*,
        next_date = 
            LEAD(T.[date], 1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY T.id
                ORDER BY T.[date])
    FROM dbo.t AS T
) AS T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- All month ends >= the current date and < next date
    SELECT
        [date] = EOMONTH(T1.[date], SV.number),
        frequency = IIF(SV.number = 0, T1.frequency, 0),
        SV.number
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
    WHERE
        SV.[type] = N'P'
        AND SV.number < ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, T1.[date], T1.next_date), 1)
) AS Expanded
ORDER BY
    T1.id,
    T1.[date],
    Expanded.number;
```

The output matches that of the recursive CTE you provided (see demo link below):

| id | date | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-30 | 5 |
| 1 | 2012-05-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-06-30 | 4 |
| 1 | 2012-07-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-08-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-09-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-10-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-11-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-12-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-01-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-02-28 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-03-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-04-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-05-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-06-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 25 |
| 2 | 2012-04-30 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-05-31 | 4 |
| 2 | 2012-06-30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012-07-31 | 6 |

### Explanation

Logically, each row from T1 is expanded by the `APPLY` into the set of month-ends that *ought* to be present. Let's look at one particular row in the source table:

| id | date | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-30 | 5 |

Adding the `LEAD` in the table expression aliased to T1 gives:

| id | date | frequency | next_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-30 | 5 | 2012-06-30 |

This row is passed to the `APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    [date] = EOMONTH(T1.[date], SV.number),
    frequency = IIF(SV.number = 0, T1.frequency, 0),
    SV.number
FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
WHERE
    SV.[type] = N'P'
    AND SV.number < ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, T1.[date], T1.next_date), 1)
```

The references to columns in T1 are *outer references*. Substituting the values from the current T1 row for `[date]`, `next_date`, and `frequency` gives:

```
SELECT
    [date] = EOMONTH('2012-04-30', SV.number),
    frequency = IIF(SV.number = 0, 5, 0),
    SV.number
FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
WHERE
    SV.[type] = N'P'
    AND SV.number < ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2012-04-30', '2012-06-30'), 1)
```

The `ISNULL` expression determines how many rows are returned from our table of numbers. In the current iteration the `ISNULL` expression evaluates to 2, so the rows returned from the numbers table have values 0 and 1.

The `APPLY` table expression as a whole returns:

| date | frequency | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-04-30 | 5 | 0 |
| 2012-05-31 | 0 | 1 |

Notice:

- When `number = 0`, we are dealing with a row that exists in T1, so we just use the frequency given.
- When `number > 0`, the row does not exist in T1 so we need to return a zero for frequency.

That gives us the results needed for the single row we chose from T1. We can do the same for the next row from T1 (substituting values as before), and so on until the result is complete. For more on how `APPLY` works logically, see my article [Understanding and Using APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1).

The only special handling is for the last row per id, where the `LEAD` returns NULL. In that case, we only need one row from the numbers table (value zero) to process the current row from T1.

---

The built-in table is sufficient for a range of dates from '2000-01-01' to '2170-08-01'.

Try the [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=429008f17ab5b9a7520c672d1698f9fd)

Answer (score 1):

Using SET Based Approach

First you need Calender Table or Number table.

```
create table CalendarDate(Dates DateTime primary key)
    insert into CalendarDate WITH (TABLOCK)  (Dates)
select top (20000)
DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,'1950-01-01') DT
from sys.objects a ,sys.objects b


Alter table CalendarDate
add EOM datetime
update CalendarDate
set EOM=eomonth(dates)
```

Populate it in whatever  way you want.

Sample data and query,

```
declare @t table(customer_ID int,lastDate datetime, Sums int)
insert into @t values
(1,'2012-04-30',5)
,(1,'2012-06-30',4)
,(1,'2013-07-31',25)
,(2,'2012-04-30',7)
,(2,'2012-05-31',4)
,(2,'2012-06-30',1)
,(2,'2012-07-31',6)

;With CTE as
(
select customer_ID,min(lastDate) minDate,max(lastDate)maxDate
from @t group by customer_ID
)
,CTE1 as
(
select customer_ID,eom from CTE t
, CalendarDate CD where cd.EOM>= minDate and cd.EOM<=maxDate
)
select c.customer_ID,eom,isnull(t.Sums,0) from CTE1 C
left join @t t on c.customer_ID=t.customer_ID and c.eom=t.lastDate
```

You should Create one very general Calendar table which will help in other requirement also.For any specific period you can do this,

```
select * from
(
select top (20000)
DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,'2000-01-01') DT
from sys.objects a ,sys.objects b
) tbl where dt<='2009-08-01'
```

Comment: I am fine with this approach, I am unable to generate calendar table properly. the date start from 2000-01-01 to 2009-08-01.  I am trying to modify the query such that it generates the dates between a specified period. When I tried the select * from sys.objects. It gave me an output which has 116  rows. And the dates are also generated of 116 rows. Is it due to this? If so, is there any way where we can change this?

Comment: @User27854,sorry for late reply,check my edited answer.