# Explode a date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, date-math

I have the following table with the following data:

```
DECLARE @MyActions TABLE (ActionId INT NOT NULL, ActionDate DATETIME NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @MyActions VALUES (1, '2021-08-01 01:00:00')
INSERT INTO @MyActions VALUES (2, '2021-08-02 02:00:00')
INSERT INTO @MyActions VALUES (3, '2021-08-03 03:00:00')
INSERT INTO @MyActions VALUES (4, '2021-08-04 04:00:00')
```

How do I explode out each ActionID into 10 additional records (5 days before and 5 days after the date for current ActionID) without using slow table value function?

ActionID = 1 should explode out to 11 total records (without the time), Action 2 should explode out to 11 total records (without the time), etc

Exploded Resultset

```
1   2021-07-27 00:00:00.000
1   2021-07-28 00:00:00.000
1   2021-07-29 00:00:00.000
1   2021-07-30 00:00:00.000
1   2021-07-31 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-01 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-02 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-03 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-04 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-05 00:00:00.000
1   2021-08-06 00:00:00.000
2   2021-07-28 00:00:00.000
2   2021-07-29 00:00:00.000
2   2021-07-30 00:00:00.000
2   2021-07-31 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-01 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-02 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-03 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-04 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-05 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-06 00:00:00.000
2   2021-08-07 00:00:00.000
3   2021-07-29 00:00:00.000
3   2021-07-30 00:00:00.000
3   2021-07-31 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-01 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-02 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-03 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-04 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-05 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-06 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-07 00:00:00.000
3   2021-08-08 00:00:00.000
4   2021-07-30 00:00:00.000
4   2021-07-31 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-01 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-02 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-03 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-04 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-05 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-06 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-07 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-08 00:00:00.000
4   2021-08-09 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cross join each source row with each of the 11 offset day values, removing the time via a conversion to date:

```
SELECT
    MA.ActionId, 
    ActionDate = 
        CONVERT(datetime, 
            CONVERT(date, 
                DATEADD(DAY, Offset.d, MA.ActionDate)))
FROM @MyActions AS MA
CROSS JOIN 
(
    VALUES
        (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0),
        (+1), (+2), (+3), (+4), (+5)
) AS Offset (d);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4c9783860830ab1c920e249ce2925a09)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I explode out each ActionID into 10 additional records (5 days before and 5 days after the date for current ActionID) without using slow table value function?

Create a [calendar table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11564/32281) and join that.